# Android "opening ripple" effect

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am looking for the effect shown bellow
[image: Propagating ripple effect]

I can't name the effect so I am unable to look for any resources online. It looks like a ripple but when I search for that all I find are ripples on buttons etc.

Does anyone have any resources on the topic?

Thanks

Comment: try android material design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your searches aren't working because that's not a "ripple" effect, but a "reveal" effect!

Here's a guide:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal

Answer (score 0):

It is called the "Circular Reveal" animation and is detailed here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Answer (score -1):

When i tap “Attach” button of Whatsapp then it displays menu with circular animation. This effect is known as Circular Reveal Animation and Ripple Effect. [See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsvP8.gif)

Learn Android Material Design - Create Circular Reveal Animation And Ripple Effect like Whatsapp. Full source code is attache with article, so you can easily download it. 
http://pulse7.net/android/android-create-circular-reveal-animation-and-ripple-effect-like-whatsapp/